# Error al cargar mi grafica, chartsjs no reconoce mis variables

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, chart.js

Intento mostrar en mi grafica el total de los pacientes obtenidos por cada mes del año 2021 pero no aparece ninguna informacion en la gráfica.

De hecho las graficas desaparecen al ejecutar el código. Al inspeccionar la página, dice que las variables labeldeMes y datosdeMes (declaradas en inicio.php) no estan definidas.

**Tabla pacientes**

```
CREATE TABLE `pacientes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `nombre_documento` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `num_documento` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `telf` int(16) NOT NULL,
  `sexo` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `embarazo` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `fecha_nacimiento` date NOT NULL
  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `pacientes`
--

INSERT INTO `pacientes` (`id`, `nombre`, `apellidos`, `nombre_documento`, `num_documento`, `telf`, `sexo`, `embarazo`, `fecha_nacimiento`) VALUES
(6, 'marta', 'mangue', 'dip', 655, 222987665, 'Femenino', '', '2021-12-28'),
(7, 'Mayo', 'Esono', 'dip', 5769, 551233234, 'Masculino', '', '2021-10-25'),
(40, 'Celso', 'NUESTRA', 'dip', 4334, 4343, 'Masculino', '', '2021-11-19'),
(41, 'Nathan', 'Narby Esimi', 'dip', 1111, 654890, 'Masculino', '', '2021-12-28');
```

**charts.js**

```
type = ['primary', 'info', 'success', 'warning', 'danger'];

demo = { 
  initPickColor: function() {
    $('.pick-class-label').click(function() {
      var new_class = $(this).attr('new-class');
      var old_class = $('#display-buttons').attr('data-class');
      var display_div = $('#display-buttons');
      if (display_div.length) {
        var display_buttons = display_div.find('.btn');
        display_buttons.removeClass(old_class);
        display_buttons.addClass(new_class);
        display_div.attr('data-class', new_class);
      }
    });
  },

  initDashboardPageCharts: function() {

  gradientChartOptionsConfigurationWithTooltipPurple = {
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      legend: {
        display: false
      },

      tooltips: {
        backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5',
        titleFontColor: '#333',
        bodyFontColor: '#666',
        bodySpacing: 4,
        xPadding: 12,
        mode: "nearest",
        intersect: 0,
        position: "nearest"
      },
      responsive: true,
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          barPercentage: 1.6,
          gridLines: {
            drawBorder: false,
            color: 'rgba(29,140,248,0.0)',
            zeroLineColor: "transparent",
          },
          ticks: {
            suggestedMin: 60,
            suggestedMax: 125,
            padding: 20,
            fontColor: "#9a9a9a"
          }
        }],

        xAxes: [{
          barPercentage: 1.6,
          gridLines: {
            drawBorder: false,
            color: 'rgba(225,78,202,0.1)',
            zeroLineColor: "transparent",
          },
          ticks: {
            padding: 20,
            fontColor: "#9a9a9a"
          }
        }]
      }
    };


    var ctx = document.getElementById("chartLinePurple").getContext("2d");

    var gradientStroke = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 230, 0, 50);

    gradientStroke.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(72,72,176,0.2)');
    gradientStroke.addColorStop(0.2, 'rgba(72,72,176,0.0)');
    gradientStroke.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(119,52,169,0)'); //purple colors

    var data = {

      
      labels: labeldeMes, //AQUI ES DONDE HE LLAMADO A MI VARIABLE para que me muestre los meses

      
      datasets: [{
        label: "Meses",
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: gradientStroke,
        borderColor: '#d048b6',
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderDash: [],
        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
        pointBackgroundColor: '#d048b6',
        pointBorderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#d048b6',
        pointBorderWidth: 20,
        pointHoverRadius: 4,
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 15,
        pointRadius: 4,
        data: datosdeMes, //AQUI ES DONDE HE LLAMADO A MI VARIABLE para los totales
      }]
    };

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: data,
      options: gradientChartOptionsConfigurationWithTooltipPurple
    });
    }
}
```

**inicio.php** este es el archivo php en donde se muestra la grafica

```
<?php include("plantillas/header.php"); ?>

$querymeses = 'SELECT Monthname(fecha_nacimiento) AS mes, count(*) AS Total FROM pacientes GROUP BY mes' WHERE YEAR(fecha_nacimiento) = '2021';
$resmeses =mysqli_query($conexion,$querymeses);
$rowmeses=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resmeses);

$labelMeses="";
$datosMeses="";

while($rowmeses=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resmeses)){
  $labelMeses=$labelMeses.$rowmeses['mes'].",";
  $datosMeses=$datosMeses.$rowmeses['Total'].",";
}
$labelMeses=rtrim($labelMeses,",");
$datosMeses=rtrim($datosMeses,",");


?>
```

Aqui declaro las variables que he ido llamando en **charts.js** para que me muestren los datos en la grafica

```
<script>
  var labeldeMes=[<?php echo $labelMeses; ?>]; //Aqui declaro la variable que muestra los meses
  var datosdeMes=[<?php echo $datosMeses; ?>]; //variable que muestra los totales de datos de cada mes
</script>

<!--CONTENIDO DE LA PAGINA -->
<section class="panelControl">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="plantillas/header.php"></a>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 titulo-panel">
                <h2 class="card-title">Panel de administración</h2>
                <p>Consulte las estadisticas de los pacientes</p>

       <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="card  custom-card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h5 class="card-category">Pacientes</h5>
                </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="chart-area">
                    <canvas id="chartLinePurple"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        
    </section>
```

Aqui incluyo footer.php este es el archivo php en donde se muestra la grafica

```
<?php

 include('plantillas/footer.php');

?>
```

**footer.php**

```
<!-- LIBRERIAS UTILIZADAS . -->

<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="librerias/bootstrap/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="librerias/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="librerias/dataTables/js/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="librerias/dataTables/js/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="librerias/dataTables/js/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="librerias/charts/chartjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="librerias/charts/charts.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Inicializando los graficos
      demo.initDashboardPageCharts();

    });
 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto se debe a que la declaración de las variables no están en el scope de la función de chart.js, debes declararla como una constante para que sea visible en dicha función.

Recuerda también que esta declaración o cualquier llamado debe estar antes de la función porque le estás agregando valor de forma dinámica con php.

```
script>
  const labeldeMes=[<?php echo $labelMeses; ?>]; //Aqui declaro la variable que muestra los meses
  const datosdeMes=[<?php echo $datosMeses; ?>]; //variable que muestra los totales de datos de cada mes
</script>

<!--CONTENIDO DE LA PAGINA -->
<section class="panelControl">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="plantillas/header.php"></a>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 titulo-panel">
                <h2 class="card-title">Panel de administración</h2>
                <p>Consulte las estadisticas de los pacientes</p>

       <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="card  custom-card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h5 class="card-category">Pacientes</h5>
                </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="chart-area">
                    <canvas id="chartLinePurple"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```